# Componentes aninhados e rotamento erro

Tags: react, react-router, django-rest-framework

Galera to desenvolvendo um sistema em react que vai consumir uma api rest em Django. Para o desenvolvimento estou usando o react, react-router-dom, mdbreact. Estava fazendo um form para criar conta de usuário e quando fui adicionar o componente  no formulario começou a aparecer um erro de falando que é nas rotas. Alguem tem alguma noção de como resolver ?

```
class ContentNewAccount extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <div className="col-6">
            <form autoComplete="off">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <MDBInput label="Nome" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <MDBInput label="Sobrenome" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <MDBInput label="Cpf" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <MDBInput label="Rg" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <MDBInput label="Contato" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <MDBSelect>
                            <MDBSelectInput selected="Choose your option" />
                            <MDBSelectOptions>
                                <MDBSelectOption disabled>Choose your option</MDBSelectOption>
                                <MDBSelectOption value="1">Option nr 1</MDBSelectOption>
                                <MDBSelectOption value="2">Option nr 2</MDBSelectOption>
                                <MDBSelectOption value="3">Option nr 3</MDBSelectOption>
                            </MDBSelectOptions>
                        </MDBSelect>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <label htmlFor="username" className="bmd-label-floating">Nome de usuário:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="username" className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="email" className="bmd-label-floating">Email:</label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password1" className="bmd-label-floating">Senha:</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password1" className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                    <div className="col form-group">
                        <label htmlFor="password2" className="bmd-label-floating">Senha (Confirmação):</label>
                        <input type="password" id="password2" className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button className="mr-1 primary-btn btn-raised">Cadastrar</button>
                <button className="secondary-btn">Cancelar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default class NewAccount extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
            <Base 
                children = {
                    <ContentNewAccount />
                } 
                title="Cadastre-se agora! Faça parte da nossa comunidade! " 
            />
        );
}
```

Esse é o código das rotas:

```
export default class Routes extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact={true} component={App} />
                <Route path="/nova-conta/" component={NewAccount} />
                <Route path="/login/" component={Login} />
            </Switch>
        </ BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```

Erro:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `ContentNewAccount`.

Comment: Não está faltando uma chave? {

Comment: Verifique Se o import da classe ContentNewAccount foi feito nesta classe que faz o roteamente.